# Tfs2010: How do I get the server path of the source file in a rename operation using a pending change in a shelf?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, command-line-interface

When I perform `tf rename $/Project/Main/File1.cs $/Project/Main/File2.cs` in TFS2010, I know that once I check in there will be a "rename" change on the `$/Project/Main/File2.cs` slot, and a "delete, source rename" change on the `$/Project/Main/File1.cs` slot.

However, while the changes are still pending, only the rename change exists as a pending change. No changes are displayed in Pending Change to indicate that `$/Project/Main/File1.cs` is being renamed. In fact, if you execute `tf status $/Project/Main/File1.cs` tf.exe claims there are no pending changes, which is totally false.

In my situation, I have a series of about 100 files that I have manually merged as part of a branch integration operation, and following a re-execution of the `tf merge` command at the command line, I am simply trying to undo the files to which they apply so that I may unshelve the merged changes.

However, the Tfs object model's `PendingChange` objects can supply me only with the `ServerPath`, which refers to the "source rename" item, not the "rename" item. I am at a loss about how I can trace my shelved pending changes to the items that would need to be undone in my workspace.

How can I get the original pre-rename server path for items in a shelf that have been renamed?

Answer (score 0):

You could get specific version to a point in time that the files mapped correctly and take note of the paths there.

Also, you could try TF Rollback.  If you supply the changeset where you manually merged those 100 files you will, at the very least, get a list of all relevant files if you rollback (you dont have to checkin the rollback but rather just use it to visualize the files).  From there, you should be able to figure out the related files.

Comment: Ah, sorry--to be clear, when I refer to pre-rename, I'm talking about the names prior to a rename operation that's still pending. I'm interested simply in doing a selective undo of those 100 files from a changeset that consists of thousands of pending changes from a merge operation between branches. The reason I want to undo them is so that I can then unshelve those same files, but I would like to use the contents of the shelveset as a driver for the undo operation to ensure accuracy.

Comment: In essence, I'm trying to implement "tf unshelve /force"

Comment: I see.  In my case I always just did a get specific version from the time the changeset still would resolve to valid paths and then figured it out.  Aside from the ideas I had I can't think of any other way to do it.  I don't think there is a way to get those paths from TF or TFPT or the UI.